# Is null pointer a valid iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector, null-pointer

I'm implementing `std::vector`-like class. Its iterators are just plain pointers. The problem is that if the vector is empty (there is no allocated buffer for elements) it returns `nullptr` as begin and end iterators. Are null pointers valid iterators?

I tried to learn `std::vector` source code in GNU C++ standard library. It looks like they use the same approach with null pointers.

But what about using `std::distance` with null pointers? It is defined as `last - first` for random access iterators. But [it is not valid to subtract null pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55747642/5447906) (at least in pure C). Ok, they can compare iterators before subtracting ([comparing null pointers is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13682952/5447906)), and if they are the same, return 0 without subtracting.

But anyway, `last - first` is assumed to be valid expression for random access iterators, but it is not because subtracting null pointers is undefined behavior.

If null pointers can't be used as iterators, what can I use instead?

**Update.** Ok, subtracting null pointers is [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27681633/5447906). Are there any other reasons why null pointer can't be valid iterator?

Comment: Why would be undefined? `nullptr` evaluates to `0`. `0-0 = 0`.

Comment: A type can have a null pointer to the type. And you can subtract two of them which, of course, yields 0. You can't de-reference them

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681633/subtraction-of-two-nullptr-values-guaranteed-to-be-zero
Maybe a dup?

Comment: @simre, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55747642/5447906)

Comment: @anton_rh That is C! This is C++. In C++ it is totally fine.

Comment: @simre C++ allows subtraction between two null pointers, but it is not due to "evaluates to `0`" (in part because null pointers do not "evaluate" to `0` in C++). The fact that C (where "evaluates to `0`" has more merit) does not allow this subtraction should tell you that your justification is lacking. Right conclusion, wrong rationale.

Comment: @JaMiT nullptr is 0: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL
So even if it wouldn't be explicitly defined, nor explicitly "disallowed", this subtraction would be well defined on the same types...    Nullptr is a fancy zero. :D Btw I understand you...

Comment: @JaMiT Try to read it again and understand what you read because it seems like you don't... Also from the standard:
It is kinda zero: https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.nullptr#1  
It is kinda zero: https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1  
It is kinda zero: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4 etc...
Yes the compiler see it differently than a zero. But under the hood, it is a zero. That's all. It is a fancy zero...

Comment: @JaMiT Even in your link someone copied the header for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56013135/14914614  `nullptr` is `nullptr_t(0)`, internally it is a void*=0. Even operator T*() simply returns a 0. A zero. :) :)